# Running the specific parts of R script

Tags: r

I would like to ask you how to make a specific menu on the begining of my script where I can select which part/parts of the script I want to run.

I made a long script for analysing my data but usually it's not necessary to run whole script so I would like to create this menu which allows me selection of the parts.

How to do step by step ?

Comment: You are not just looking for `utils::menu` in combination with putting your parts in distinct functions that can be called according to the menu selection?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow - we expect questions here to relate to **specific programming problems**. Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `?select.list` function and then put your expressions in `if` statements. Something like the following should work. Just fill the statements with your actual code and use more descriptive names instead of `"Part 1"` and `"Part 2"`.

```
parts <- select.list(c("Part 1", "Part 2"), # use descriptive names here
                     multiple=TRUE, 
                     graphics=TRUE, 
                     title="Which parts should be run")
# perhaps some calculations are always necessary
if ("Part 1" %in% parts){
# write some actual code
  print("Runs the first part")
}
if ("Part 2" %in% parts){
  # write some actual code
  print("Runs the second part")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In RStudio, under Code, there is Run Region, and under that there is Run Code Section.  If you define your parts as Sections, that could assist.  Or, you can run from your current position to the end with the Run from Line to End choice.

Answer (score 1):

Most of my scripts have settings in the first few lines. This includes things like the working directory, time zones, and *stuff*. So, to control what parts of the script run, I just set a bunch of flags in this part of the script, like...

```
do.part1 <- TRUE
do.part2 <- TRUE
```

then I wrap different bits of the code in `if` loops. For example:

```
if (do.part1){
    # write some actual code
    print("Runs the first part")
}
if (do.part1){
    # write some actual code
    print("Runs the second part")
}
```

It's not elegant, but it has the advantage that it just runs and doesn't require any more user input.